# Elsticsearch : Contains query

Tags: ajax, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a column in my mapping that holds an array of strings

```
col1
["asd","fgh","wer"]
["qwer","cvbvbn","popop"]
["cvbml","fhjhfrjk","fsdfd"]
["asd","trth","fdf"]
```

The column `col` is not analyzed in the index and i do not want to change the mapping.

```
"col1":
{
    "type":"string",
    "index":"not_analyzed"
}
```

Now, i want to retrieve all records where the string `asd` appears. so in this case, i want the first and fourth records. I tried using the query

```
        query: {

                    wildcard:{
                        "col1":"asd"
                    }
                }
```

with

```
POST localhost:9200/indexName/test/_search
```

but that gives me empty results? Which query should i use in this case?

**Edit**

So i was able to solve the above problem. Here is a follow up. Consider that this was my data

```
col1
["asd fd","fgh bn","wer kl"]
["qwer","cvbvbn","popop"]
["cvbml","fhjhfrjk wewe","fsdfd rtr"]
["asd","trth","fdf"]
```

so now, the array contains some strings that have multiple words. Now, i still want to return the first and fourth record. If i go with the solution that i posted, i only get the fourth one. How can i apply the `contains` logic to each element of the array in `col1`?

**Note**

A partial solution is

```
{ "query": { "match_phrase_prefix": { "col1": "asd" } } }
```

so again, for the data

```
col1
["asd fd","fgh bn","wer kl"]
["qwer","cvbvbn","popop"]
["cvbml","fhjhfrjk wewe","fsdfd rtr"]
["asd","trth","fdf"]
```

it returns the first and fourth records. However, if i have

```
col1
["fd asd","fgh bn","wer kl"]
["qwer","cvbvbn","popop"]
["cvbml","fhjhfrjk wewe","fsdfd rtr"]
["asd","trth","fdf"]
```

then, once again it only returns the fourth one, which is understandable as now, `asd` is no longer a prefix for that value in the first record.

**Is there a way to to a `contains` type match instead of just prefix match?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `term` query and it should work

```
POST localhost:9200/indexName/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "terms": { "col1" : "asd" }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work, as it gives me empty set. i figured it out, please see my answer

Comment: My bad, `terms` instead of `term`, indeed.

Comment: thanks, please see the edit. i have a follow up. can you please help with that?

Comment: also, this would also work

query: {
         
         match:{
          
          col1: "asd"
         }
        }

Answer (score 0):

so, here is the proper query

```
{

                    fields : ["col1","col2"],
                    query: {
                        filtered: {

                          query: {
                            match_all: {}
                          },
                          filter: {
                            terms: {
                              col1: ["asd"]
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }

                }
```

**Final Answer**

```
    query: {

                wildcard:{

                  col1:{

                          value:"*asd*"
                       }
                }
            }
```

:)